# Java - How to read ints or doubles/floats of a file

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I have this code so far, but I am having trouble with using the delimiter (I am new to regex as well as file reading).

```
File file = new File(ROOT_FOLDER + fname);

    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=\\D+)(?=[^\\.])");
        scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(p);

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String next = scanner.next();
            UI.println(next);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
        if (scanner != null)
            scanner.close();
    }
```

Sample of a file

```
Samples from database of fake names from http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/
All details are fictious!!

Mr. Jake M Goodwin 11 Yarmouth Road Mahora 4120 JakeGoodwin@teleworm.us (022) 6735-347 1998 Rolls-Royce Silver Spur 100.9 184
Mr. Samuel D Law 140 Small Street Dunedin Central 9016 SamuelLaw@cuvox.de (028) 0699-710 2001 Dodge Durango 113 180
```

What's getting to me is that if I use the default space delimiter, then numbers like `(028)` won't be detected as a number with `hasNextDouble()` (but using a regex I think means I can just use `hasNext()` instead anyway).

What is the proper delimiter I need to use? I am thinking of something like: Any number of non-digits and in a row, as long as it isn't a single dot.

Comment: Can you give a sample input and output for your program?

Comment: .
The occasional number or solo dot, or dot followed by number, among a crapload of spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
try
    {
        //regex for matching only numbers and dot
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^0-9.]");
        scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(FILE_PATH)).useDelimiter(p);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String next = scanner.next();
            if(!next.equals("") && !next.equals(".")) {
                System.out.println(next);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (scanner != null)
            scanner.close();
    }
```

Input :

> Samples from database of fake names from http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/
>   All details are fictious!!Mr. Jake M Goodwin 11 Yarmouth Road Mahora 4120 JakeGoodwin@teleworm.us (022) 6735-347 1998 Rolls-Royce Silver Spur 100.9 184
>   Mr. Samuel D Law 140 Small Street Dunedin Central 9016 SamuelLaw@cuvox.de (028) 0699-710 2001 Dodge Durango 113 180

Output :

> 11
>   4120
>   022
>   6735
>   347
>   1998
>   100.9
>   184
>   140
>   9016
>   028
>   0699
>   710
>   2001
>   113
>   180

Comment: Wow that's so much simpler than using regex. I feel like I've thought of that before but rejected it in my mind in favour of the more complex regex solution. Thanks!

Comment: Why is there no `\\` before the `.` in your regex? I thought `.` meant any character. And also, does the `0-9.` mean a `0-9` digit and then a `.` or does it mean `0-9` or a `.`

Comment: A bracket expression [] matches a single character that is contained within the brackets. For example, [abc] matches "a", "b", or "c".
^0-9. means negated set - matches any character that is not in set.

Comment: I see. So does the ^ mean everything but 0-9, or everything but 0-9 or a dot

Comment: Means everything but 0-9 or dot. A very good place where you can practice is on [RegExr](http://regexr.com/)